# How to use LOOKUP from two different sheets?

Tags: date-range, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have a Calc document that has N sheets. First sheets are equal and contain some data. Last sheet is a summary.

My problem is that I need to use the LOOKUP function in the last sheet to look up for data in the N-1 previous sheets. This doesn't work:

```
=LOOKUP(X, Sheet1.A1:Sheet9.A100, Sheet1.B1:Sheet9.B100)
```

In this case it's valid a solution that requires to hardcode the sheets, i.e.:

```
=LOOKUP(X, FANTASTIC_JOIN_FUNCTION(Sheet1.A1:A100;Sheet2.A1:A100;Sheet3.A1:A100; ... ), FANTASTIC_JOIN_FUNCTION(Sheet1.B1:B100;Sheet2.B1:B100;Sheet3.B1:B100; ...))
```

but I don't know which is this `FANTASTIC_JOIN_FUNCTION`...

Any idea?

Comment: Does the data contain numbers or strings?

Comment: @JimK Data. A1:A100 are dates and B1:B100 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put this in cell A1 (or somewhere else that is convenient) on the summary sheet:

```
=LOOKUP(X, Sheet1.$A$1:$A$100, Sheet1.$B$1:$B$100)
```

In cell A2 put this:

```
=LOOKUP(X, Sheet2.$A$1:$A$100, Sheet2.$B$1:$B$100)
```

Continue this way for N-1 rows.

Now we need to get rid of #N/A errors.  To do this, put this in cell B1:

```
=IF(ISNA(A1),"",A1)
```

Then fill this formula down N-1 rows.

Finally, merge the values into a single cell.  For numerical data. this works:

```
=SUM(B1:B100)
```

For text data, concatenate all N-1 cells in the B column, for example:

```
=B1&B2&B3&B4&B5
```

Comment: This is not as clean as I'd like, but I'll work :) Thanks